# View Controller Not Loading its Subview (table view) Properly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'am new in ios and i'am doing an project I have used `baseviewcontroller` for every `viewcontroller` and i'm creating a profile on sign up and sign in but my `viewcontroller` is not loading its `subview` properly.

here is `Tableview` inside my `viewcontroller`

[image]

This is my tableview ..it is not fitting properly and this problem is in every viewcontroller

Comment: You have to apply autolayout constraints to make it run seamless on all iOS devices. Right now It is showing 320 pixel width. Put a constraint from tableView to container of Equal width. If you run it on iPhone 5s simulator, you will not experience this issue. Right now you are running it on 6s+.

Comment: are you using AutoLayout ?

Comment: No i'm not using constraints,ok i'll try it on iphone 5s

Comment: thanx nsnoob it has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn Auto Layouts, use constraints.
2. Code the frame(more importantly width in your case) of tableView like following:

`{ self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height); 
 }`

Comment: For some reason, I can not put the code in proper format. Somebody edit it.

Comment: can you refer me the link to learn autolayout programatically

Comment: Better do it on Storyboard, this is a start: [Auto Layout] (http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Comment: For Auto Layouts programmatically: [Apple: Auto Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1)

Comment: Thnxx Arpit,But programmatically It's easy for me for future modication and I can understand it more clearly